# How to overcome 412 status yielded by the Python Requests package?

Tags: python, python-requests

Why is my python script using the `requests` package not able to download the tar.gz file while BASH's `wget` command is able to? It complained that the requested resource could not be found (412). How do I overcome this issue?

**Update:**
I discovered that after deactivating the VPN my python script could work. It would not work when VPN is activated. However, `wget` worked when the VPN is and is not activated. Why is this the case? Is there some settings that need to be done on `requests` to overcome the 412 status?

My Python3.6 script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pathlib import Path
import requests
import sys


def download_sdk( url, sdkname ):
    print( f'\nDownloading SDK...' )
    print( f'url = {url}' )
    print( f'sdkname = {sdkname}' )
    r = requests.get( url )
    #response less than 400 response, open in binary mode and write sdk to user defined vulkan directory
    if r.ok: 
        with open( sdkname, "wb" ) as file:
            file.write( r.content )
    else:
        sys.exit( print( f'Quit: requests_status_code={r.status_code}' ) )
    print( f'\nDownload Completed.' )
    return True


sdk = f'vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.1.121.1.tar.gz'
url = f'https://sdk.lunarg.com/sdk/download/1.1.121.1/linux/{sdk}?u='
sdkname = Path.cwd() / sdk
download_sdk( url, sdkname )
```

Python script's output:

```
Downloading SDK...
url = https://sdk.lunarg.com/sdk/download/1.1.121.1/linux/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.1.121.1.tar.gz?u=
sdkname = /home/master/Vulkan/Installers/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.1.121.1.tar.gz
Quit: requests_status_code=412
```

BASH's  `wget` command is able to download the tar.gz file.

```
$ wget https://sdk.lunarg.com/sdk/download/1.1.121.1/linux/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.1.121.1.tar.gz?u=
--2020-06-17 23:11:28--  https://sdk.lunarg.com/sdk/download/1.1.121.1/linux/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.1.121.1.tar.gz?u=
Resolving sdk.lunarg.com (sdk.lunarg.com)... 2604:86c0:5000:3::3, 38.143.66.106
Connecting to sdk.lunarg.com (sdk.lunarg.com)|2604:86c0:5000:3::3|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to sdk.lunarg.com (sdk.lunarg.com)|38.143.66.106|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Syntax error in Set-Cookie: u=H0TJAB4JavYv3jKUtK1SDiu2UjlaBDHatNkvDosqN8ppYXwEVEX45Z60GLqE%0A6k5%2BerCS3KZHcD8RhV7liLcoYQ%3D%3D; ; path=/; SameSite=Lax at position 100.
Syntax error in Set-Cookie: a=XZxs35QBwvluz8x%2Bgl5n4w%3D%3D; expires=Fri, 10 Jun 2050 15:11:31 +0000; ; path=/; SameSite=Lax at position 74.
Length: 119858765 (114M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.1.121.1.tar.gz?u=’

vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.1.121.1.tar.gz?u=           100%[====================================================================================================================>] 114.31M   576KB/s    in 3m 12s  

2020-06-17 23:14:43 (610 KB/s) - ‘vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.1.121.1.tar.gz?u=’ saved [119858765/119858765]
```

Comment: those arent the same url, `...sdk/download/1.1.121.1...` != `...sdk/download/1.1.121.0...`

Comment: @TenaciousB Thanks for pointing it out. My bad...  I have corrected it but received 412 status. What should I do now?

Comment: @TenaciousB I discovered that after deactivating the VPN my python script could work. It would not work when VPN is activated. However, I notice `wget` worked when the VPN is activated? Is there some settings that need to be done on `requests` to overcome 412 status?

Comment: messages from `wget` show that it tried two connections and it failed on first one `2604:86c0:5000:3::3`. Maybe it also get `412` and after that it try connection `38.143.66.106` and it download file. Maybe `requests` has similar problem with `2604:86c0:5000:3::3` and it would need some method to use different connection. OR maybe if VPN uses `IP6` then you would have to turn it off and keep only `IP4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this function and `urllib.parse.urljoin()` to generate the url:

```py
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin

def download(url, path):
    response = requests.get(url) # get the response of the ink
    with open(path, 'wb') as file: # create the file
        file.write(response.content) # write the contents of the response to the file

base_url = 'https://sdk.lunarg.com/sdk/download/1.1.121.1/linux/'
sdk = 'vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.1.121.1.tar.gz'
query = '' # if you need to adda query stirng like '?u=' but that didn't make a difference in this case
url = urljoin(base_url, sdk, query) # make the full url
print(url)

download(url, f'./{sdk}')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. After troubleshooting my original code for a few days, I found that my original code worked with and without activating VPN. That is, the 412 requests_status_code returned by `requests` had disappeared. I did not manage to discover how the VPN had caused the issue. The rest of your code looks the same as my, except it did not have a loop to check the status of the returned object by `requests`. Appreciate your pointer on using `urllib.parse.urljoin` to add query string.